# Datatable disable search option searchable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Here is my code, I'm trying to disable search on all column except one on global search.
This always search for the primary key I have defined. Using the datatable example server side class.

```
var datatable = $('#datatable').DataTable({
        "ajax": "/get_data/",
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "deferRender": true,

        "columns": [
            {"searchable": false, "data": "id"},
            {"searchable": false, "data": "user_id"},
            {"searchable": true, "data": "bl_number"},
            {"searchable": false, "data": "invoice_number"},
            {"searchable": false, "data": "ship_date"},
            {"searchable": false, "data": "eta_date"},
            {"searchable": false, "data": "vessel"},
            {"searchable": false, "data": "port_of_load"},
            {"searchable": false, "data": "port_of_discharge"},
            {"searchable": false, "data": "containers"},
            {"searchable": false, "data": "status"}
        ],

        "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });

    datatable.on('click', '.btn-edit', function(){
        var data = datatable.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
        edit(data);
    });
```

If I use array instead of json object I could use the following code and it works fine. But I need to work with Json objects not array.

```
var datatable = $('#datatable').DataTable({
    "ajax": "/get_data/",
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "deferRender": true,

    "columnDefs": [ 
        {
            "targets": 0,
            "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                return '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn-edit">Edit</a>';
            }
        },
        { targets: 1, searchable: true },
        { targets: '_all', searchable: false }
    ]
});

datatable.on('click', '.btn-edit', function(){
    var data = datatable.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
    edit(data);
});
```

Comment: when using serverside processing in datatables, everything becomes kind of manual. In your function get_data in the php, you need to retrieve the value you are trying to search for, and filter the columns you want (in the sql query)

Comment: @Dacklf Datatable samples have have a server side class included, and datatable on front end send column which the search is applied. by default it sends all columns. I need one as you can see in my provided code which works.

Comment: Ok, I don't know if it's the issue, but in your second sample of code, you are targeting '1' and '_all'. First you make '1' searchable, and then you make '_all' not searchable. Maybe with the second targeting you are also making '1' not searchable. So try changing the order.

Comment: The 2nd example works fine. Its the intended way documented in docs. The rules works on priority from top to bottom. I need help with same implementation using 1st example or json objects instead of array.  https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs